# Как идти по тегам в selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

У меня есть дискорд сервер в виде сайта. И я хочу с того сервера выбрать людей и добавидь мне в беседу. Можно ли на селениум идти поочередно по тегам или нет? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


option = Options()
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars") 
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdr\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=option)

browser.get('site)

elem  =  browser.find_element(что ищем,  'тег что ищем' )
либо
elements1=soup.find_all(attrs={"класс":{"тег"}})
find_all ищем все классы с таки тегом, find ищем первый тег
```